# Hardhat tests for ERC777 not passing and breaking other tests

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, dapps, hardhat

While trying to pass tests for two solidity functions, I get stuck on two tests:

```
23 passing (4s)
  2 failing

  1) Treasury
       getBalance
         should return updated balance after depositing more tokens:
     Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=2, expectedCount=4, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
      at Logger.checkArgumentCount (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:340:18)
      at /home/brsh/WebstormProjects/dsb/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:187:12
      at step (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
      at /home/brsh/WebstormProjects/dsb/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:23:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:19:12)
      at populateTransaction (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:152:12)

  2) Treasury
       deposit
         "before each" hook for "should deposit ETH successfully":
     Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266","data":"0x60806040523480156200001157600080fd5b50604051620024fb380380620024fb8339810160
```

The second issue appeared after I implemented the ERC777 feature in the deposit function.
It looks like this:

```
function deposit(
        address tokenAddress,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes calldata userData,
        bytes calldata operatorData
    ) external payable nonReentrant  {
        require(amount > 0, "Treasury: Deposit amount must be greater than zero");
        require(msg.value == amount, "Treasury: amount mismatch");
        require(!isLocked, "Treasury: Contract is locked");
        if (tokenAddress == ETH_ADDRESS) { // ETH
            
            emit DepositETH(tokenAddress, msg.sender, amount);
        } else {

            IERC165 tokenContract = IERC165(tokenAddress);
            if (isERC777(tokenAddress)) {

                IERC777(tokenAddress).send(address(this), amount, abi.encode(userData, operatorData));
                emit DepositERC777(tokenAddress, msg.sender, amount);

            } else if (tokenContract.supportsInterface(type(IERC20).interfaceId)) {

                require(allowedTokens[tokenAddress], "Treasury: Token not allowed");
                SafeERC20.safeTransferFrom(IERC20(tokenAddress), msg.sender, address(this), amount);
                emit DepositERC20(tokenAddress, msg.sender, amount);

            } else {
                revert("Treasury: Unsupported token type");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the SampleERC77:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/IERC777Sender.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/IERC777Recipient.sol";
import "./ITreasury.sol";

contract SampleERC777 is ERC777, IERC777Recipient {

    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        address[] memory defaultOperators
    ) ERC777("Sample ERC777", "S777", defaultOperators) {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply, "", "");
    }

    function tokensReceived(
        address operator,
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes calldata userData,
        bytes calldata operatorData
    ) external override {
        require(to != address(0), "SampleERC777: zero address not allowed");
        if (ITreasury(to).isTreasuryContract()) {
            ITreasury(to).deposit(operator, from, amount, userData, operatorData);
        }
    }
}
```

and here are all the failing tests:

```
  // getBalance tests
    describe("getBalance", () => {
        beforeEach(async () => {
            const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("SampleERC20");
            token = await Token.deploy();
            await token.deployed();
            await token.mint(treasury.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("100"));
        });


        it("should return updated balance after depositing more tokens", async function () {
            await treasury.connect(tokenManager).addAllowedToken(token.address);
            await token.mint(owner.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("50"));
            await token.connect(owner).approve(treasury.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("50"));
            await treasury.connect(owner).deposit(token.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("50"));
            const balance = await treasury.getBalance(token.address);
            expect(balance).to.equal(ethers.utils.parseEther("150"));
        });
    });


    // deposit tests
    describe("deposit", function () {
        let Treasury, treasury, SampleERC20, sampleERC20, SampleERC777, sampleERC777, owner, tokenManager, user1, user2;

        beforeEach(async function () {
            // Get the ContractFactory and Signers here.
            [owner, tokenManager, user1, user2] = await ethers.getSigners();

            const initialSupply = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1000");

            Treasury = await ethers.getContractFactory("Treasury");
            treasury = await Treasury.deploy();
            await treasury.deployed();

            SampleERC777 = await ethers.getContractFactory("SampleERC777");
            sampleERC777 = await SampleERC777.deploy(initialSupply, [treasury.address]);
            await sampleERC777.deployed();

            // Grant token manager role
            await treasury.grantRole(await treasury.TOKEN_MANAGER_ROLE(), tokenManager.address);

            // Add ERC20 and ERC777 tokens to allowed tokens
            await treasury.addAllowedToken(sampleERC20.address);
            await treasury.addAllowedToken(sampleERC777.address);

            // Mint some tokens for user1 and user2
            await sampleERC20.connect(owner).mint(user1.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("100"));
            await sampleERC20.connect(owner).mint(user2.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("100"));
            await sampleERC777.connect(owner).mint(user1.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("100"), "0x", "0x");
            await sampleERC777.connect(owner).mint(user2.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("100"), "0x", "0x");
        });

        it("should deposit ETH successfully", async function () {
            const depositAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");

            await expect(
                treasury.connect(user1).deposit("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", depositAmount, { value: depositAmount })
            ).to.not.be.reverted;

            expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(treasury.address)).to.equal(depositAmount);
        });

        it("should deposit ERC20 tokens successfully", async function () {
            const depositAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther("10");
            await sampleERC20.connect(user1).approve(treasury.address, depositAmount);
            await treasury.connect(user1).deposit(sampleERC20.address, depositAmount);

            expect(await sampleERC20.balanceOf(treasury.address)).to.equal(depositAmount);
        });

        it("should deposit ERC777 tokens successfully", async () => {
            const depositAmount = ethers.utils.parseUnits("100", 18);
            await sampleERC777.connect(user1).send(treasury.address, depositAmount, "0x");

            const user1TreasuryBalance = await treasury.connect(user1).balanceOf(user1.address);
            expect(user1TreasuryBalance).to.equal(depositAmount);
        });

        it("should emit Deposit event on successful deposit", async () => {
            const amount = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1000", 18);
            await token.connect(owner).approve(treasury.address, amount);
            await token.connect(owner).transfer(user1.address, amount);

            await expect(treasury.connect(user1).deposit(token.address, amount))
                .to.emit(treasury, "Deposit")
                .withArgs(user1.address, token.address, amount);
        });

        it("should revert when trying to deposit non-allowed token", async function () {
            const anotherTokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SampleERC20");
            const anotherToken = await anotherTokenFactory.deploy();
            await anotherToken.deployed();
            await anotherToken.mint(owner.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("1000"));

            await anotherToken.connect(owner).approve(treasury.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("500"));
            await expect(treasury.connect(owner).deposit(anotherToken.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("500"))).to.be.revertedWith(
                "Treasury: Token not allowed"
            );
        });

        it("should revert when token transfer amount exceeds balance", async () => {
            const treasuryBalanceBefore = await erc20Token.balanceOf(treasury.address);
            await expectRevert(
                treasury.deposit(erc20Token.address, treasuryBalanceBefore.add(new BN("1")), { from: user1 }),
                "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance"
            );
        });

        it("should revert when not enough tokens are approved for transfer", async function () {
            const sender = owner;
            const amountToTransfer = ethers.utils.parseEther("100");
            const amountToApprove = ethers.utils.parseEther("50"); // Less than the amountToTransfer

            await token.connect(sender).approve(treasury.address, amountToApprove);

            await expect(treasury.connect(sender).deposit(token.address, amountToTransfer))
                .to.be.revertedWith("SafeERC20: low-level call failed"); // Since SafeERC20 wraps the error message
        });

        it("should revert when token transfer fails", async function () {
            await token.connect(owner).approve(treasury.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("500"));
            await expect(treasury.connect(owner).deposit(token.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("1500"))).to.be.revertedWith(
                "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance"
            );
        });

        it("should revert when trying to deposit a zero amount", async function () {
            await token.connect(owner).approve(treasury.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("500"));
            await expect(treasury.connect(owner).deposit(token.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("0"))).to.be.revertedWith(
                "Treasury: Deposit amount must be greater than zero"
            );
        });

        it("should revert when trying to deposit an amount greater than approved", async function () {
            await token.connect(owner).approve(treasury.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("400"));
            await expect(treasury.connect(owner).deposit(token.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("500"))).to.be.revertedWith(
                "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"
            );
        });

        it("should correctly update the treasury balance after multiple deposits", async function () {
            // Before depositing tokens in the treasury, approve the treasury to spend tokens on behalf of the owner
            await token.connect(owner).approve(treasury.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("1000"));
            await treasury.connect(owner).deposit(token.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("300"));
            await treasury.connect(owner).deposit(token.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("200"));
            const balance = await treasury.getBalance(token.address);
            expect(balance).to.equal(ethers.utils.parseEther("500"));
        });
    });
```

In the deposit function, only the "should revert when trying to deposit a zero amount" and the "should revert when trying to deposit non-allowed token" work, the "should deposit ETH successfully" was working as well and after I added the ERC777 part, it failed. Here is more relevant parts on the contract:

```
  constructor() {
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);

        _grantRole(TOKEN_MANAGER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(NFT_MANAGER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(LOCK_MANAGER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(WITHDRAWER_ROLE, msg.sender);

        // Add the project token to the allowedTokens mapping
        allowedTokens[projectToken] = true;
        allowedTokens[ETH_ADDRESS] = true;
    }



    function isERC777(address tokenAddress) private view returns (bool) {
        bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("granularity()");

        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = tokenAddress.staticcall(payload);

        return success && (returnData.length == 32);
    }
    
    function getBalance(address token) external view returns (uint256) {
        require(allowedTokens[token], "Treasury: Token not allowed");

        if (token == address(0)) {
            return address(this).balance;
        }
        return IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));
    }
```

I'm stuck for a long time on the deposit tests and I don't know further, I tried different approaches but they lead to the same errors, it might be an issue in the functions that I'm not able to see... Maybe I didn't implement ERC777 properly.

Answer (score 0):

this error:

```
 Error: missing argument: passed to contract (count=2, expectedCount=4, code=MISSING_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
```

It mean that the number of arguments passed to the contract is not the same as the number of arguments expected by the contract

at the line `await treasury.connect(owner).deposit(token.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("50"));`

replace it with `await treasury.connect(owner).deposit(token.address, ethers.utils.parseEther("50"), "0x", "0x");`

then this error

```
Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account", method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266","data":"0x60806040523480156200001157600080fd5b50604051620024fb380380620024fb8339810160
```

mean that the gas estimation failed because the function call reverted, it look like it is due because the function call is being made to a non-contract account

in this test

```
it("should deposit ETH successfully", async function () {
    const depositAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");

    await expect(
        treasury.connect(user1).deposit("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", depositAmount, { value: depositAmount })
    ).to.not.be.reverted;

    expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(treasury.address)).to.equal(depositAmount);
});
```

you also have to pass the `userData` and `operatorData`

```
await expect(
    treasury.connect(user1).deposit("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", depositAmount, "0x", "0x", { value: depositAmount })
).to.not.be.reverted;
```

Comment: The first error is related to getBalance() function:

`function getBalance(address token) external view returns (uint256) {
        require(allowedTokens[token], "Treasury: Token not allowed");

        if (token == address(0)) {
            return address(this).balance;
        }
        return IERC20(token).balanceOf(address(this));
    }`
After following your advice I get this:
` getBalance
         should return updated balance after depositing more tokens:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Treasury: amount mismatch' `

Comment: there is a mismatch between the amount of tokens that the deposit function expects and the actual amount of tokens being deposited